# Using a comma before with "with"

Tags: prepositions, commas

I am trying to document some code and this sentence sounds confusing.

> Replaces the existing item associated with the provided key
>   with newItem.

I am tempted to put a comma here but I am not sure if it would be correct.

> Replaces the existing item associated with the provided key,
>   with newItem.

If it's incorrect, how can I state my intention clearly?

Comment: Having the worth "with" twice is your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write:

> Replaces the existing item, which is associated with the provided key, with newItem
>
> Replaces the existing item, associated with the provided key, with newItem.

And if the key is something that's common between the two *items*, then you could say something like this:

> [With the provided key it] replaces the existing item with newItem.

Or

> Replaces the existing *item* with *newItem* based on the provided key.

Comment: I like your Option 2, and the O.P. may even want to consider using dashes: _Replaces the existing item – associated with the provided key – with newItem._

Comment: @J.R. Yea, I think that sounds better.

Comment: +1 I think this is what it is. Though rephrasing would be definitely better.

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have been looking at it too long.  I see what you mean, but a comma doesn't add anything.  My suggestion is to either simply italicize *newItem* as in:

> Replaces the existing item associated with the provided key with *newItem*.

or change it to something like:

> Replaces the provided key's currently associated item with newItem.

Comment: NB: You don't need a hyphen between *currently* and *associated*. You're linking an adverb with an adjective, not two adjectives to a noun. The adverb modifies the adjective, not the noun.

Comment: @Robusto removed.